# how to show list view record in textview on setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have created simple list view,what i want to do is that when user  click on list view,selected record should show in text view in my code it work properly,but problem is that when user again click i want to show that record in second text view,please give me idea/code how to do this..please please help me...i am new in android..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String item[]=new String[]{"rk","kk","kk","ll","mm","uu"};
TextView tv,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;    
ListView li;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    li=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setText);\
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setText1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setText2);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setText3);      
    tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setText4);      

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, item); 
    li.setAdapter(adapter); 
    li.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int itm=position;       
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+itm+""+li.getItemAtPosition(position),40).show();
        tv.setText(""+li.getItemAtPosition(position));
    }
});
```

Comment: how many TextViews do you have ?

Comment: when user select one record it show in first text view,When user select second  list view record it should show in second text view and so on..

Comment: from your code you have only one TextView

Comment: ok will create five text view then..

Comment: check my answer with code

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm understanding you right. You want different textviews to have text depending on how many tiems it's clicked.If so, set a static counter to count how many times it's clicked. In your **OnItemClick** increment this counter and check for it's value, then set the text of the TextViews depending on it's value.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int itm=position;       
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+itm+""+li.getItemAtPosition(position),40).show();
    if (myCounter >=2){
        someTextView.setText(""+li.getItemAtPosition(position));
    }else{
        anotherTextView.setText("blabla")'
        }
}
```

Edit: Make an ArrayList holding your TextViews in the correct order. Using the position int given in OnItemClick you can take out the correct TextView and use .setText on them!

Comment: please check it i updated my code,i have created 5 text view,now when user click on list view first row it should show in in first text view, when user click on list view second row it should show on second text view..

Comment: Please check my edit and see if it is what you needed

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can deal with it.

```
 ArrayList<Boolean> firstTimers = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

 for (Int I =0; I< item.length(); I++){
   firstTimers.add(false);
  }

 li.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if( !firstTimers.get(position ){
         int itm=position;       
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+itm+""+li.getItemAtPosition(position),40).show();
          tv.setText(""+li.getItemAtPosition(position));
          firstTimers.set(position,true);
       }else{ // show in other textview
         }
}
});
```